# JTextArea not scrolling when needs to

Tags: java, swing, scroll, jtextarea

UPDATE: I have managed to solve this by removing the

```
f.pack()
```

at the bottom of the constructor method. Please let me know if this is a bad way of solving the problem.

---

I have a JPanel and to it I've added a JTextArea. This text area should scroll and when text is added to it, it should automatically scroll to the bottom.

However, when I enter enough text for the pane to start scrolling, this happens instead.

Before scrolling:
[image]

After scrolling should occur:
[image]

Here is the relevant code:

```
public class GameGUI2 extends JFrame implements ActionListener                                                                                                 
{                                                                                                                                                              
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;                                                                                                           
   JFrame f = new JFrame("Dungeons of Doom");                                                                                                                 
   JPanel textPanel = new JPanel();                                                                                                                           
   JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());                                                                                                        
   JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());                                                                                                       
   JPanel moveButtonPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());                                                                                                  
   JPanel extraButtonPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());                                                                                                 
   JPanel mapPanel = new JPanel();                                                                                                                            
   JTextArea mapTextArea = new JTextArea(10, 10);                                                                                                             
   JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(20, 50);                                                                                                                
   JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);

   // Extra stuff to do with updating the map

   // Making the buttons

   public GameGUI2()                                                                                                                                          
   {                                                                                                                                                          
       // Making the GridBagConstraints                                                                                                     

       // Setting the insets for the constraints                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

       f.setBounds(100, 100, 1000, 600);                       

       // Adding a scrolling text area to a panel.                                                                                                                                                    
       textPanel.add(scrollPane);                                                                                                              

       // More work with constraints                                                                                               

       f.getContentPane().add(leftPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);                                                                                                  
       f.getContentPane().add(rightPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);                                                                                                 

       textArea.setEditable(false);                                                                                                                           
       mapTextArea.setEditable(false);                                                                                                                        

       this.setVisible(false);                                                                                                                               

       // Constraint work for the buttons and map

       leftPanel.add(moveButtonPanel, leftTopC);                                                                                                              
       leftPanel.add(extraButtonPanel, leftBottomC);                                                                                                          
       leftPanel.add(mapPanel, mapC);                                                                                                                         

       mapPanel.add(mapTextArea, mapC);                                                                                                                       

       textC.gridx = 0;                                                                                                                                       
       textC.gridy = 0;                                                                                                                                       
       textC.gridwidth = 3;                                                                                                                                   
       textPanel.add(textArea, textC);                                                                                                                        

       rightPanel.add(textPanel, textC);                                                                                                                      

       // Adding buttons to panel                                                                                                                    

       // Adding action listeners for the buttons                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

       f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);                                                                                                   
       f.pack();                                                                                                                                              
       f.setVisible(true);                                                                                                                                    
   }                     

   public void displayInGUI(String fromServer)                                                                                                                
   {                                                                                                                                                          
      textArea.append(fromServer);         
      // Making the text area scroll to the bottom automatically.                                                                                                                   
      textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getDocument().getLength());                                                                                         
   }
```

Why isn't my textArea scrolling? Have I misunderstood something?

I know there are questions similar to this. One says that the problem is coming from setting the preferred size of my JTextArea, so I tried this changing the line:

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(20, 50);
```

To:

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
```

and remove:

```
textC.gridx = 0;                                                  
textC.gridy = 0;                                                  
textC.gridwidth = 3;                                            
textPanel.add(textArea, textC);
```

But then this happened:

[image]

Many thanks.

Comment: Change `textPanel.add(textArea, textC);` to `textPanel.add(scrollPane, textC);` you're basically removing the `textArea` from the `scrollPane` which isn't what you really want. As it stands, you have an empty `JScrollPane` floating around your layout. Removing `pack` generally isn't the solution

Comment: @MadProgrammer thank you, this makes sense. I've done this but I still have the same problem.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses